# Weird Float Rounding - different results for different tables using the same value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to reconcile `float` data between two tables, and I'm coming across some weird behavior with the `ROUND` function.  For example, the underlying value in the table is 4754792087.72.

For one table, `ROUND(fieldName,5,1)` will result in the expected 4754792087.72.

For another table, the same function call on the same value will result in 4754792087.71999 - it somehow adds precision.  For this table if I try `round(convert(numeric(28,10),fieldName),5,1)` I still get the 4754792087.71999 value, and the same happens with `cast` instead of `convert` or using `decimal` instead of `numeric`.

I realize the `float` datatype is weird and non-precise, but converting to `numeric` and `decimal` doesn't resolve the issue.  There weren't any obvious differences between the setup of the two tables that I could see.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `I'm trying to reconcile float data` - well, I think I found your problem. :-)

Comment: `float` isn't imprecise, per say, but the values it represents are base 2 values not base 10. When you start dealing with non integer values, then things start to become problematic.

Comment: Kidding aside, what version of SQL Server? And in `sys.columns` are `precision` and `scale` identical? Maybe they were created with different types (`float(<>24)` vs. `real` which is a `float(24)`). Can you reproduce this by recreating the tables in a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle)? Also what if you use `numeric(28,2)` if you only care about 2 decimal places? You're using float and round and too many decimal places, so you're practically _begging_ for weird outcomes

Comment: Thanks Aaron - for sys.columns all the values look the same between the two column definitions - system_type_id, user_type_id,max_length,precision,scale, etc.  I haven't been able to reproduce it in a different table (temp table or table variable) exactly, but when putting the float data in a table variable and converting to numeric it does add some precision starting in the 6th decimal place, though it's not exactly the same values.  We're on SQL 2017, though this database is on 110 compatibility level.  Some data from this vendor is divided by 1000 so I need to have 5 decimal places.

Comment: Right but if you _need_ five decimal places but you _expect_ `.72` instead of `.71999`, you can go to `28,2` then back out to `28,5` and have `.72000`.

Comment: That will work with this value, but that's basically just rounding to 2 decimal places and putting 000 at the end of that to make it a 5-decimal-place number, right?

Comment: Yes, but again, we don't know what you actually expect in other cases because you've only shown us this one case, so what else can we do but suggest a way to workaround for the one case you've shown us? Are both tables in the same database on the same server? Was one created on a much older version? What happens when you create a new version of the table that's broken, copy the data there, and then try again? This is a wild goose chase for us, FWIW.

Comment: One way floats defined differently can actually store/display the wrong information: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35f429c034de67805d21ae74a1798a9b). As others have suggested (on this question and on many others), if you want reliably accurate and consistent calculations of decimal numbers, use decimal, not float.

Comment: Fair enough!  This discussion convinced me that the most appropriate way forward here is to get close enough on reconciling the existing float data, then transition the processes to a new table using decimal instead of float.  Thanks for your help!